# Exception when converting text to words

Tags: c#, windows, text-to-speech

I've been using the Microsoft Silvia synthesizer for many years and I've never had any problems. This morning it stopped working and this error comes back:

> `No entries in the system or no entry available with the security`

This is the code I use:

```
SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
var voiceList = ss.GetInstalledVoices();
ss.SelectVoice(voiceList[0].VoiceInfo.Name); 
ss.Volume = 100; 
ss.Rate = 0; 
ss.SpeakAsync("123");
```

Comment: I don't know what this is, but it is not C

Answer (score 1):

Strange but effective solution: the same code executed on Visual Studio 2019, with the same target framework, works perfectly!